# Race condition when calling components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios

I have 2 components which are being loaded into an "App", the first component resolves the external ip address to a geo by making 2 axios.get calls and then returns them (via emit) to App.vue.

I then call "Weather" to resolve the lat/long from the previous 2 calls to some json returned by the darksky API for that lat/long.  Sometimes (50-60% of the time) I am hitting a race condition where I am sending 0/0 to weather (which are what I initialize lat/long to in App.vue) and don't know how to resolve it.  I would like the following code to run more reliably.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <ip @response="onResponse" /> //Needs to finish before next line runs (has axios calls)
    <Weather msg="The weather for:" :lat="lat" :long="long" :ip="ip" :city="city" :country="country"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Weather from './components/Weather.vue'
import ip from './components/ip_resolve.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      lat: 0,
      long: 0,
      ip: 0,
      country: 0,
      city: 0 
    }
  },
  components: {
    Weather,
    ip
  },

  //Accepts emitted values from ip_resolve -- needs to change values in data before Weather runs
  methods: {
    onResponse(event) {
      this.lat = event.lat
      this.long = event.long
      this.ip = event.ip
      this.country = event.country
      this.city = event.city
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

ip_resolve.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="Hemlo">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios').default;
const ipRegex = /ip=(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})$/gmi
export default {
  name: 'ip',
  props:{
      ip: String,
      country: String,
      City: String,
      lat: Number,
      long: Number
  },
  mounted () {
    axios.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace')
    .then(response => (
        this.ip = ipRegex.exec(response.data)[1]
    )
        .then(
            axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.ipstack.com/'+this.ip+'?access_key=<key>')
            .then( response => (
                    this.lat = response.data.latitude,
                    this.long = response.data.longitude,
                    this.country = response.data.country_name,
                    this.city = response.data.city
                ).then(
                    this.$emit('response', {
                        ip: this.ip,
                        lat: this.lat,
                        long: this.long,
                        country: this.country,
                        city: this.city
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

Weather.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="Hi">
    <h1>{{msg}} {{city}}, {{country}}</h1>
    <h2>Temp: {{ temp }}f</h2>
    <h2>Conditions: {{ conditions }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

const axios = require('axios').default;
export default {
  name: 'Weather',
  props: {
    msg: String,
    resp: String,
    ip: String,
    lat: Number,
    long: Number,
    city: String,
    country: String,
    temp: String,
    conditions: String
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/<key>/'+this.lat+','+this.long)
      .then(response => (
        this.resp = response.data,
        this.temp = response.data.currently.temperature,
        this.conditions = response.data.currently.summary
      ))
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide another components code too

Comment: @Justice47 -- added more code, but I am quite certain that the code in ip_resolve / weather aren't so much the issue, as it's just that I need to wait for ip_resolve to finish before weather is invoked.

Comment: I thought JavaScript was a single threaded language.

Comment: @duffymo it is, but you still write a lot of async code.

Comment: @A_Elric you can re-make your components system to make requests in one component (via `.then()` after first request) or use `Vuex` and `watch` for change

Comment: I'd be writing this as callbacks/promises.  I wouldn't allow any calls until both are done.  The language doesn't support joining two threads, so you have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would separate out this model logic into its own module, using something like vuex, so the data flow for components is completely uni-directional.

But in this case, the simplest solution is to add a `v-if="responseReady"` directive to the `<Weather>` component in App.vue so that it does not get mounted until the data is ready. You will also need to add a boolean flag for this new prop to `data` and `onResponse`.  Again, this is the quick and dirty solution.

```
  <Weather v-if="responseReady"  msg="The weather for:" :lat="lat" :long="long" :ip="ip" :city="city" :country="country"/>
...
  data() {
    return {
        lat: 0,
        long: 0,
        ip: 0,
        country: 0,
        city: 0,
        responseReady: false
      }
    }, 
...
    onResponse(event) {
      this.lat = event.lat
      this.long = event.long
      this.ip = event.ip
      this.country = event.country
      this.city = event.city
      this.responseReady = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you have anywhere that goes over recommended architecture for async operations in Vue / Veux?

Comment: (Also -- for anyone reading this later, ng-if should be v-if for Vue )

Comment: @A_Elric Thanks, fixed that little bug (currently converting an angular app to vue so the wires crossed in my brain). As for the recommended architecture point, start by reading https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html and then continue by reading the vuex docs. After that, the more heady architectural stuff tends to get covered by blog posts, but if you try to keep your components view-focused you should be in good shape.